# Use release or snapshot repository for manual deployment depending on the project version

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin, build-helper-maven-plugin

I want to configure a manual file deployment to a remote repository using either the snapshot repository (using configured property project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url) if the current version of the project is a snapshot version or to the release repository (using configured property project.distributionManagement.repository.url) otherwise.

I want to deploy a swagger json schema to the repository and I did not find any way other than a manual deployment.

Comment: Please, could you explain in which way does your need diverge from the standard Maven behavior?  Because my first impression is that the standard behavior suits your needs

Comment: I have made an update with the reason of the manual deployment.

Comment: The release or snapshot repository will be decided by the version which you use. This means if you use something like `XXXX-SNAPSHOT` it will be deployed to snapshot repository and if you use something without `-SNAPSHOT` it will be deployed to release repository...So what I don't understand is why you need to do something different? Manually doing a deployment can be done by `mvn deploy`?

Comment: using manual deployment (with deploy-file goal) does not use the distribution management configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work around using builder helper bsh to use the correct repository from the distribution management configuration. It sets a property with the correct value. Then the maven deploy plugin is called with the goal deploy-file and this URL.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>bsh-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>deploy.url</property>
                </properties>
                <source>deploy.url = project.getVersion().endsWith("-SNAPSHOT") ? project.getDistributionManagement().getSnapshotRepository().getUrl() : project.getDistributionManagement().getRepository().getUrl() ;</source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>${deploy.url}</url>
                <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
                <file>${swagger.directory}/swagger.json</file>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <packaging>json</packaging>
                <classifier>swagger</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to deploy some artifact (maybe a json text file) that has not a corresponding pom.xml file supporting it, you may use the deploy-file target:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html

This allows you to deploy any kind of artifact from any origin into a maven repository, specifying by command line the group, artifact and version coordinates, and anything else you need.

In order to deploy it to the right place depending on your version, I can propose you this fragment of an ant script we built for a similar purpose:

```
<condition property="url" value="${snapshots.repo.url}" else="${releases.repo.url}">
            <contains string="${project.version}" substring="-SNAPSHOT"/>
        </condition>
        <exec executable="cmd">
            <arg value="/c"/>
            <arg value="mvn.bat"/>
            <arg value="deploy:deploy-file"/> 
            <arg value="-DgroupId=com.myorg.swagger"/>
            <arg value="-DartifactId=swagger_file"/>
            <arg value="-Dversion=${project.version}"/>
            <arg value="-U"/>
            <arg value="-Dfile=./mydir/my_swagger_file.json"/>
            <arg value="-Durl=${url}"/>
            <arg value="-DrepositoryId=my_repo_id"/>
          </exec>
```

This will only work in Windows, but is easily adaptable for any other OS.  The interesting bit here is the repositoryId, that should point to an existing authentication in your settings.xml:

```
...
<servers>
        <server>
            <id>my_repo_id</id>
            <username>your_user_for_deployment</username>
            <password>your_pwd_for_deployment</password>
        </server>
</servers>
...
```

Hope this will help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

@Nicolas Henneaux answer is correct but `deploy` phase in `build-helper-maven-plugin` is incorrect. New properties are visible in next stage of lifecycle so in this case it won't be visible. After removing it (the defeault is validate) everything started to work.

Comment: I made the change, I tested it a while and it might have changed, no impact to use the default phase to add the property anyway. Thanks for sharing